# No 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'DynamicTableViewCell?'

Tags: swift

Implementing a custom table view cell and getting the below error on dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, can any one please help.

code :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        //static DynamicTableViewCell *cell = nil;
        var cell : DynamicTableViewCell?

        var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        dispatch_once(&token) { () -> Void in
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
        }

        self.setUpCell(cell!, indexPath: indexPath)

        return self.calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell(cell!)

    }
```

Comment: ***static Dynamic**TableViewCell* is a contradiction in terms. This code cannot work at all. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is meaningless.

Comment: I have commented that line and i am not using it, I have a objective c version of same which works refer :- https://github.com/tjosten/iOS-UITableViewCell-with-dynamic-height/   I am trying to write that in swift

Comment: May be you should use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier only in tableView's method cellForRowAtIndexPath. And for custom cell you should register your custom class while loading controller ( for example in viewDidLoad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your way of doing it is a stable enough solution, but the Objective-C code you pointed can be translated into Swift as:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    struct My {
        static var cell : DynamicTableViewCell?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&My.token) { () -> Void in
        My.cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? DynamicTableViewCell
    }

    self.setUpCell(My.cell!, indexPath: indexPath)

    return self.calculateHeightForConfiguredSizingCell(My.cell!)
}
```

The error message *No 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'DynamicTableViewCell?'* is saying that the return type of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is `UITableViewCell?` which cannot be assigned to a variable of type `DynamicTableViewCell?`. You just need an explicit cast to suppress this error.

But other than that, you need to make your local `cell` and `token` static.

And you should also know that Swift 3 has excluded `dispatch_once` from its Standard Library.